# What are the possible methods to start a PPTP VPN connection on boot?

Tags: boot, vpn, pptp

I use to connect to my **remote PPTP VPN** server by doing:

```
# pon MyVPNConnection persist holdoff 60 maxfail 0
```

I would like to automate this connection to be **executed on system boot**, so I have added that line to `/etc/rc.local` .

But, for what I have heard, it is better to use **some other method**, like initialization scripts or `rc.d`.

**One of the method** that works for me requires adding to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto tunnel
 iface tunnel inet ppp
         provider MyVPNConnection
```

This works, but only for my installed on hard disk Linux, not for my own customized live distributions, due to `/etc/network/interfaces` is modified by the squashfs on each boot.

So, there is any other method or initialization script to **start my PPTP VPN** network connection on boot?

Maybe something like:

```
# update-rc.d pptp enable
```

This above method works for OpenVPN clients fine.

Comment: I was searching for something like that too without success